# Add Subview to MKCircleRenderer, iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mkmapview

in iOS 6 I used to add a `UIImageView` to a `MKCircleView` and animate it in this way:

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeCircle.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
imageView.alpha=0.7f;
[self addSubview:imageView];
```

Since `MKCircleView` has been deprecated, now I am using `MKCircleRenderer` but I can't add anymore a `subview`.

Is there a way to add a `UIImageView` to a `MKCircleRenderer`?

Comment: How about subclassing MKCircleRenderer and override drawRect to draw your image?